# Textbox remains disabled even though the java script was supposed to enable it

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

Quite a simple question I have here, but it gave me quite a headache -

```js
document.getElementById("yourText").disabled = true;
document.getElementById('yourBox').onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById('yourText').enabled = this.checked;
};
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label asp-for="IsGate"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="yourBox" asp-for="IsGate">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label asp-for="Condition"></label>
  <input type="text" id="yourText" asp-for="Condition">
</div>
```

This is supposed to enable the textbox when `IsGate` is checked, and disable it when it is not checked. After setting it disabled by default, it remains like that even when the checkbox is changed.

[image]

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.enabled` is not a valid property. Use always `.disabled` and `!this.checked` to inverse the logic

```js
const el_yourText = document.getElementById('yourText');
const el_yourBox  = document.getElementById('yourBox');

el_yourText.disabled = true;

el_yourBox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  el_yourText.disabled = !this.checked;
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label asp-for="IsGate"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="yourBox" asp-for="IsGate">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label asp-for="Condition"></label>
  <input type="text" id="yourText" asp-for="Condition">
</div>
```